# Why I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error even though I can see the header in postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, express

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  User.find()
    .sort({ name: -1 })
    .then(theUsers => {
      res.json(theUsers);
    });
});
```

I have put the header. It also shows in postman. Why does it keep blocking me?

[image]

I have also put * on the value but still does not work.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Have you had a look at CORS with express?

Answer (score -1):

why not use cors in your server.js file set it before the line where your routes are.

`npm install cors`

`const cors = require("cors")`

`app.use(cors())`

then your route here

`app.use("/api",routes)`